# Why does MSVC think that the input parameter to this function is of type int, although it's not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, declaration

I tried to learn about the implicit `this` pointer and its uses, but I can't seem to understand why my compiler (MSVC) keeps talking about `int` as the type for the function `printcmon()`, instead of `cmon`.

```
void printcmon(const cmon* e);

class cmon
{
public:
    int x, y;
    cmon(int x, int y) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            printcmon(this);
    }

    int getX() const {
        const cmon* e = this;
        std::cout << e->x << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

void printcmon(const cmon* e) {
    //stuff
}
```

Errors:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*'
error C2664: 'void printcmon(const int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'cmon *' to 'const int'

message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
message : see declaration of 'printcmon'
message : while trying to match the argument list '(cmon *)'
```

Comment: You get downvotes because you have posted the text as a link to a picture.

Comment: You have a function declaration for `void printcmon(const cmon* e);` so that you can call it in  `cmon::cmon()` because the compiler wouldn't know the function otherwise. The same goes for the type `cmon` which is used in the declaration. You can add `class cmon;` before your function declaration to tell the compiler that you have a class called `cmon`.

Comment: @273K  i see, is that not liked in stack overflow?

Comment: No its not. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on it.

Comment: The first error I [see](https://godbolt.org/z/98nYKGvGs): `<source>:1:22: error: 'cmon' does not name a type`

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question does not need debugging details. It's quite clear what's being asked.

Comment: @Evg OP is using Visual Studio and is not compiling with gcc and therefore gets different error messages. Those from gcc are definitely better in this case though. Using msvc I get [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6vTvhejxK) errors, which are basically the same as in OPs image.

Comment: @Joel I see. If the error screenshot is replaced with plain text with real line numbers, it'll be a good question.

Comment: @PeteBecker The question needs debugging details because it does not include the error as text.

Comment: The bug is `void printcmon(const cmon* e);` at this point `cmon` is not a type that compiler knows about. You need a forward declaration.

Comment: @PeteBecker We need a better list of reasons for closing questions and better training for new folks. Right now some people don't want to waste their time studying how to ask before asking their first question and others don't want to waste their time to copy-paste references to what should have been studied.

Comment: @Evg -- need better training for high-rep folks to not bully newcomers. For example, don't say "why do you think X" when you mean "X is incorrect". And (this is harder than it sounds) instead of "you do X..." say "the code does X".

Comment: @PeteBecker I've never seen that anybody bullies newcomers here. What I see is that newcomers start asking questions before reading any information in the help center about how to ask questions. All major problems are explained there, one has only to read it. This is a two way road, if new folks expect to get answers to their questions, they are expected to read how this site works.

Comment: @Evg -- I gave you an example. It's easy to fall into condescension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class **cmon** before first line `void printcmon(const cmon* e);`
Add a declaration:

```
class cmon;
void printcmon(const cmon* e);

class cmon
{
public:
    int x, y;
    cmon(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        printcmon(this);
    }

    int getX() const {
        const cmon* e = this;
        std::cout << e->x << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

void printcmon(const cmon* e) {
    //stuff
    
}
```